# Prove: $X$ is well orderable $\implies$ $X \times X$ is well orderable

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing, set-theory, well-orders

I am studying a course on ZF Set Theory and have recently been considering whether or not $X$ being well orderable implies that $X \times X$ is well orderable.

More formally my question is the following:

> **Prove:** “$X$ being well orderable implies that $X \times X$ is also well orderable”

It seems obvious to conclude that the answer here is the affirmative and intuitively it is easy to see why this is the case (where the minimal element of $X \times X$ will be the element $(a,a)$ where $a$ is the minimal element of $X$ **and** each subset of $X \times X$ will have a minimal element which will be the ordered pair $(c,d)$ where $c$ is the minimal element of the first subset of $X$ and $d$ is the minimal element of the second subset of $X).$

However, constructing a proof of the claim is where I am having difficulties. Is there a suitable reference or proof available to make my intuition more rigorous?

As suggested in the comments, this can be achieved using the lexicographic ordering, however, I would still be interested in seeming a formalisation of this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Being well ordered is much more than just having a minimal element. Every nonempty subset has to contain a minimal element. Anyway, here is a hint: given a well ordering of $X$, define the lexicographic order on $X\times X$. (i.e the order first compares the first coordinates, and if they are equal then compares the second coordinates)

Comment: If I may offer a piece of unsolicited advice here, you've been asking *a lot* of "can we do this and that without AC", of course, this is the way to learn. But it seems to me that it would be beneficial for you to just get a grasp on what and how AC is used in proofs first, then a lot of these questions would be a lot easier to tackle.